# salesforce lightning event e.force:navigateToComponent is disabled now?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Yestoday e.force:navigateToComponent is accessble but today  salesforce lightning event e.force:navigateToComponent is disabled ? why?

Comment: believe this method was never officially enabled for outer world and now it might be restricted for internal use only

Comment: That is correct - the component was never marked access="global" or documented as part of the S1/SFX public API. We do have plans to provide this type of functionality publicly in an upcoming release.